# Azure Synapse Copy from Dynamics 365 to .csv always fails for one table

Tags: azure-synapse

I'm trying to copy activitymimeattachment from Dynamics 365 (dataverse) to .csv files using Synapse Analytics.

There are over 1,000,000 rows in table.  Every time it fails at around 225,000 rows with message below.

Other tables in Dynamics are copying successfully.

```
{
    "dataRead": 11936153352,
    "dataWritten": 5976883200,
    "filesWritten": 0,
    "sourcePeakConnections": 1,
    "sinkPeakConnections": 3,
    "rowsRead": 215000,
    "rowsCopied": 215000,
    "rowsSkipped": 0,
    "copyDuration": 1936,
    "throughput": 6386.385,
    "redirectRowPath": "",
    "logFilePath": "copyactivity-logs/copyactivity-logs/Copy_fdo/7491d67c-de51-467c-b251-3ee5668a1fc3/",
    "errors": [
        {
            "Code": 9011,
            "Message": "Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorFailedFileOperation,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The file operation is failed, upload file failed at path: 'engdynamicsfs/activitymimeattachment.txt'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,''Type=System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException,Message=The remote server returned an unexpected response: (502) Bad Gateway.,Source=mscorlib,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway.,Source=System,'",
            "EventType": 0,
            "Category": 5,
            "Data": {
                "FailureInitiator": "Source"
            },
            "MsgId": null,
            "ExceptionType": null,
            "Source": null,
            "StackTrace": null,
            "InnerEventInfos": []
        }
    ],
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime (UK South)",
    "usedDataIntegrationUnits": 4,
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "DataMovement",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "AzureIR",
                "duration": 2.1999999999999997,
                "unit": "DIUHours"
            }
        ]
    },
    "usedParallelCopies": 1,
    "executionDetails": [
        {
            "source": {
                "type": "Dynamics"
            },
            "sink": {
                "type": "AzureBlobFS"
            },
            "status": "Failed",
            "start": "3/7/2023, 9:05:12 AM",
            "duration": 1936,
            "usedDataIntegrationUnits": 4,
            "usedParallelCopies": 1,
            "profile": {
                "queue": {
                    "status": "Completed",
                    "duration": 4
                },
                "transfer": {
                    "status": "Completed",
                    "duration": 1930,
                    "details": {
                        "readingFromSource": {
                            "type": "Dynamics",
                            "workingDuration": 1861,
                            "timeToFirstByte": 61
                        },
                        "writingToSink": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFS",
                            "workingDuration": 71
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "detailedDurations": {
                "queuingDuration": 4,
                "timeToFirstByte": 61,
                "transferDuration": 1869
            }
        }
    ],
    "dataConsistencyVerification": {
        "VerificationResult": "NotVerified"
    },
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
    }
```

We have another table - activitypointer - that is also large.  This has copied successfully.

We have run this as a single table copy, no other tables included.

We have retried and are confident this is not a transient error.

Enabled logging and fault tolerance.  Log file has no content other than headers:

Timestamp,Level,OperationName,OperationItem,Message

Comment: I can only suggest that you use filters in your extraction to try and narrow down and isolate the bad row(s)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - that feels like looking for a needle in a haystack!  I was wondering if there were any volume/time limits I was hitting.  It feels like this always happens at 30 minutes.

Comment: It's not a needle in a haystack, you'll probably find the record(s) in question after a dozen iterations. For example first you should order your data then find some filters that will narrow the data down. At least using this method you can confirm whether it's data or time. Maybe in the first instance just order them in the other direction

Comment: It's actually a tried and tested troubleshooting approach. You just zone in on the offending record by divide and conquer. This way you at least work out if a specific record is causing the issue or not, and often when you see the offending data the penny drops